# Git hooks and auto-generated documentation

Tags: git

I just set up my Python project to use `pdoc`, which automatically generates HTML documentation, and I added the docs to the repo.

I want the docs to update automatically each time I commit the code, so I made a `pre-commit` hook that runs `pdoc`.

Expected behavior: I open the commit dialog in my GUI, the hook runs and updates the HTML files, and I commit the HTML files together with my code changes.

Actual behavior: the GUI doesn't call `git commit` until after I'm done staging changes and writing the commit message. So the HTML files update only after the commit is committed. This behavior is the same in Tortoise and Git Extensions.

Workaround: commit the code first, then amend with the documentation updates.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: You shouldn't add generated files to the repo.  It bloats it and causes merge conflicts.

Comment: Bloat is a relative term. And if I resolve the merge conflicts in my code, I can auto-generate conflict-free copies of the documentation.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having my users run `pdoc` themselves. I figured it would be difficult to set up. But maybe adding the documentation to the repo is more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [bk2204 suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68946010/git-hooks-and-auto-generated-documentation#comment121849092_68946010), it's likely that the *best* way is not to have the generated files in this repository.  (Whether to store them anywhere, and if so where, is another question.)

There are, however, sometimes reasons to store some sort of autogenerated files: for instance, perhaps the program that generates them is not available to most users, even though the project itself is public.  In this case, the rule you should use in Git is simple:

- Have your pre-commit hook check to see if the to-be-committed files are correct.
- If so, let the commit proceed.
- If not, reject the commit.

Then, instead of running `git commit` (or using some clicky GUI button that runs `git commit`), run `make newcommit` or `./build-and-commit` or whatever.  This builds the autogenerated files if/as needed, runs `git add` on them if/as needed, and runs `git commit`.  If your GUI has the proper sub-structure,<sup>1</sup> you can convert the "make new commit" button to do this.

---

<sup>1</sup>Alas, only "toy" GUIs written in Tcl/Tk seem to have this.  Maybe I just keep coming across bad GUIs.